# CouchDB view results contain "missing" docs after purging

Tags: couchdb

After purging a set of documents in a Couch database, some view results contain documents which are actually not there in the database. When accessing such documents following error message is returned

```
{"error":"not_found","reason":"missing"}
```

Also the view results contain duplicate entries for some of such "missing" documents.
Some of these docs contain conflicted revisions as well.

Following is a simple view which lists such documents. According to the view, there should not be duplicate results.

```
function(doc) {

    if (doc.documentType == 'theDocType') {
        emit(theDocType, doc);
    } 
}
```

I created a new document with an id of a "missing" document, and tried purging it again (giving the new rev and all the conflicting revs). But after purging, the view results remained same as earlier.

Any idea what has caused this and how to resolve this problem ?

Comment: I got this after a clone as well, but the view is skipping over a document that is there

Answer (score 0):

I just recently had this issue too and found your question.

I fixed it by deleting the view records, stored here on Windows

```
"...\couchdb.2.1.1\data\.dbname_design\mrview\*.view"
```

here on Linux

```
<couch data directory>/.dbname_design\mrview*.view (usually /var/lib/couchdb or /usr/local/var/lib/couchdb)
```

Each .view is named with an md5, delete them all, then restart the service.  Then request the view again and it will rebuild this index, it might take 2 or 3 attempts before it builds it properly depending on the size of the database.

Hopefully someone can add what the linux path is.

Comment: The linux path also is the <couch data directory>/.dbname_design\mrview\*.view (usually /var/lib/couchdb or /usr/local/var/lib/couchdb)
Deleting view indexes and letting them re-index will solve the above problem. But still, the exact root cause needs to be found.